# Select a portion of an IP

Tags: ruby, string

Say I have the IP address `10.0.0.47`
How can I manipulate it cleverly so that I am left with `10.0.0.`?
`chop` sprang to mind, but it's not dynamic enough. I want it to work regardless if the number after the last `.` consists of 1 or 3 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`String#rindex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-rindex) and [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) with range:

```
ip = "10.0.0.47"
ip[0..ip.rindex('.')] # from the first character to the last dot.
# => "10.0.0."
```

or using regular expression:

```
ip[/.*\./]      # greedy match until the last dot
# => "10.0.0."
```

or using [`String#rpartition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition) and [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
ip.rpartition('.')[0,2].join
# => "10.0.0."
```

Comment: `rindex` was an interesting find, great!

Comment: @krystah, I just added another alternative (`rpartition` + `join`)

Answer (score 3):

```
str[/(\d+\.){3}/]
# => "10.0.0."
```

Comment: Correct use of `String#[]`.. +1